# How to display 24-hour format time in Slack?

Tags: slack

On https://slack.com/, how do I display message timestamps in 24-hour format instead of AM/PM?

Comment: See the [support page](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/213893898-Change-your-message-display-settings) for slack that shows exactly how.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver bam there's the answer. don't know how I missed it, thanks!

Comment: Hated to actually copy paste that into an answer :->

Comment: @Gypsy: You should anyway. This allows for the Asker to mark it as accepted, which acts as a signpost to future readers looking for the same solution. I've added a [Community Wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/21960) answer, but if you'd like to add your own please feel free to do so and I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

From [Slack support](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/213893898-Change-your-message-display-settings):

> 1. Click your team name to open the Team Menu.
> 2. Choose Preferences.
> 3. Select the Messages & Media tab.
> 4. Check out the Message Theme and Display Options settings.
>
> You can adjust other message-related settings under Display Options:
>
> ...
>
> - **Show times with 24-hour clock**
>   Choose between 24-hour and 12-hour times (e.g. 16:12 or 4:12 PM).

Comment: It works. However slackbot still uses 12-hour clock.

Comment: setting this option only half works. I still see "Call Ended
Ended at 3:56 PM - Lasted 10 minutes"

Comment: Surprising that this menu is not reached by clicking the Menu icon, the three lines in the top left corner

Comment: How is that setting not in the "Language & Region" tab?